# Shifting all label values far from axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a surface plot but problem is that my tick label and axis label overlap each other. Is there any way to shift the label in all axis far from tick labels? I actually need to keep the tick label font bigger so making that smaller is not an ideal for my case.[image]

Comment: You can use plt.xlabel(labelname, labelpad=20) or something larger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Several ways you can set this

For all axes with `rcParams` using

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['axes.labelpad'] = 20.0
```

---

Individually (for an axis handle) with

```
ax.xaxis.labelpad = 20
ax.yaxis.labelpad = 20
ax.zaxis.labelpad = 20
```

if you do not have an axis you can precede this with

```
ax = plt.gca()
```

---

When you create the labels

```
plt.xlabel("X Label", labelpad=20)
plt.ylabel("Y Label", labelpad=20)
plt.zlabel("Z Label", labelpad=20)
```

or for an axis handle

```
ax.set_xlabel("X Label", labelpad=20)
ax.set_ylabel("Y Label", labelpad=20)
ax.set_zlabel("Z Label", labelpad=20)
```

---

Here is a complete example using some randomly generated data

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import rcParams
rcParams['axes.labelpad'] = 20.0

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,9))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

XS = np.random.randn(100)
YS = np.random.randn(100)
ZS = np.random.randn(100)

ax.scatter(XS, YS, ZS, c='r', marker='o')
plt.title("3D Scatterplot")
ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')
plt.show()
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Your answer would be better suited at the duplicate, in case not all of those options are mentionned there.